# OpenMP seems to bind its threads to different cores but the actual affinity masks allow the use of all cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, affinity

Using x64 msvc v19.29 on a AMD Ryzen 9 5900X (12 cores, AMD's Hyper-Threading-equivalent disabled), a program parallelized using only `omp_set_num_threads( 10 );` and `#pragma omp parallel for schedule( dynamic, 1 )` *seems* to bind the one master and nine worker threads to different cores. Observing the Windows Task-Manager, 10 cores are 100 % utilised while two cores are more or less idle. The idle and unitised cores change for every restart of the program but the observed behaviour remains the same. Checking the thread affinity for each thread within a *static* OpenMP loop using the return value of `SetThreadAffinitMask( . )` shows that all threads are allowed to run on all 12 cores.

By contrast, using a C++17-based thread pool (here the master thread does not conduct any work and the 10 worker threads all of it), severe thread ping-pong can be observed and there are no quasi-idle cores. Needless to say, the performance of the OpenMP variant is significantly superior.

My question is, which mechanism is used by OpenMP to cause the observed behaviour if it is not binding the threads to different cores? How can the behaviour be replicated via the Windows API?

As a side note, I am hesitant to use OpenMP since it is not guaranteed to work with C++11 or higher constructs (to the best of my knowlede and ignoring experimental settings, Visual Studio does only support OpenMP 2.0).

Edit 1: Answering J. Richard's question

```
auto getMask =
  []( HANDLE handle )
  {
    auto mask = DWORD_PTR{ 1 };
    mask = SetThreadAffinityMask( handle, mask );
    SetThreadAffinityMask( handle, mask );
    return mask;
  };

std::vector< DWORD_PTR > masks( 10 );

#pragma omp parallel for schedule( static, 1 )
for ( auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
  masks[ i ] = getMask( GetCurrentThread() );
}
```

Every element of `masks` equaled 4095 (decimal) or 111111111111 (binary).

Comment: The performance difference you measured is surprising. It sounds like the algorithm (as written to whatever thread pool you are using) is not well crafted. There would still be overhead if you are thrashing the thread pool on every small iteration. So don't do that.

Comment: Can you precise how did your check the affinity with `SetThreadAffinitMask` and the *exact* results?